# SimpleDateFormat print "." for MMM format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert date string from one format to another using SimpleDateFormat.
Conversion works but there is a dot "." after month.

```
    String dateStr = "04/02/1987";
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date d = df1.parse(dateStr);
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    System.out.println(df2.format(d));
```

Output is **04 Feb. 1987** instead of **04 Feb 1987**.

Comment: Please don't use the obsolete `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes. The have been superseded by classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the old cumbersome legacy `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` class instead of the classes from `java.time`? like `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: By the way, my guess it that the dot appears because of your locale? What is your default `Locale` (returned by `Locale.getDefault()`)?

Comment: When using `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`, It returns `04 Feb 1987`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide Locale.ENGLISH in SimpleDateFormat constructor while creating object as shown below:

```
String dateStr = "04/02/1987";
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = df1.parse(dateStr);
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(df2.format(d));
```

Answer (score 4):

**What is your `Locale.getDefault()`?**

Different output for alphanumeric date parts may be caused by the `Locale` the formatter is using. In most cases, the system default `Locale` is used if you don't specify one yourself. I don't know for sure `SimpleDateFormat` does so, but it seems likely.

I know that a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` does so, see the following example which uses `java.time`, the modern and recommended to use datetime API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateStr = "04/02/1987";
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy",
                                                                    Locale.ENGLISH)));
    System.out.println(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy",
                                                                    Locale.FRENCH)));
}
```

Output:

```
04 Feb 1987
04 févr. 1987
```

The output is (of course) different concerning the name of the month, but using `Locale.FRENCH` shows a dot after the abbreviated month name. It is possible that your system's default `Locale` is one that indicates an abbreviation by a dot, too, but is identical to the output format of a `Locale.ENGLISH` for the numeric parts **and** the abbreviation of the month.